# Is there a non-ajax way to repeatedly poll an external js file?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

would really appreciate any help with this JS question. 
Have been experimenting for an hour or so now and haven't bumped into anything that does the trick.

---

**Current Setup**

- Website 1: the 'content' site. This site displays different content depending on whether a user is logged into website 2 or not. I'm using a script tag in the head with the src set to a PHP file located on website 2.
- Website 2: the 'user management' site. This uses PHP to output in a 'javascript' file whether a user is logged in (i.e. as a js var).

---

Currently this setup works fine for checking whether a user is logged into website 2 system when a user *loads the page* on website 1.

However, rather than a once-off check, I'm wanting the PHP file on website 2 to be polled every 2 seconds to see if the loggedin status has changed.

Is there a way to do this in vanilla javascript? (i.e. without ajax or jq - I'm trying to keep the whole system small and known).

> If it's relevant, a friend suggested putting a randomly generated variable at the end of the PHP file name to prevent caching. (He didn't know how it could be repeatedly polled though!)

Comment: I'd consider AJAX vanilla javascript - you do not need to use third party libraries to use it (however it does help iron out the cross browser intricities). Also jQuery has built-in methods to help prevent caching (I believe it appends a random querystring for you). You could use frames or synchronous calls - but both have downfalls.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you could create an interval function changing the `src` property of a script element in your page?

```
setInterval(
  function(){
    myscript.src = '/urltophp?'+someRandomKey;
  }, 2000);
```

Where `someRandomKey` prevents the script being cached in the browser. A `script` tag can have an `id`, so it's retrievable using `document.getElementById`

To create a random key this may help:

```
function randomKey(iLen) {
  var sKey = ''
  , isKey = ''
  , i = 0
  , aRanges = ['48,9', '65,25', '97,25'];
  iLen = !iLen ? 4 : iLen;
  while (i < iLen) {
    var aRange = String(aRanges[Math.round(Math.random() * 2)]).split(',');
    isKey += String(aRanges[Math.round(Math.random() * 2)]) + ',';
    sKey += String.fromCharCode(Math.round(parseInt(aRange[0], 10) +
        (Math.random() * parseInt(aRange[1], 10))));
    i++;
  }
  return sKey;
}
```

Comment: For random key `new Date().getTime()` would probably be simpler - the 2 second interval makes sure it won't clash ;)

Comment: @Martin Jespersen: yep, didn't think of that. Well, it's a multi purpose random key generator for free then ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){


    $('#divtoloadcontentin').load('urlofscript' + '&nocache=' + Math.random()*Math.random());

}, 5000);
```

The only reason the divloadcontentin is their is because you could load in a php date() function to show users how up to date the page is.